# DataGrid, стиль ячейки

Tags: wpf, xaml

Я хотел бы настроить стиль пользовательской ячейки, чтобы у неё не было границ ово всех состояниях: выделена/не выделена. Я написал следующий стиль:

```
<DataGrid.Resources>
     <Style TargetType="DataGridCell" x:Key="borderNone">
          <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
     </Style>
</DataGrid.Resources>
```

Он работает почти так, как надо. А именно, убирает границу выделения ячейки. Но, осталась следующая проблема:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот эта чёрная граница справа и снизу ячейки. Видна во всех состояниях. Как её убрать? Спасибо. На всякий случай полный код таблицы(эта ячейка - собственная, настроенная):

```
<DataGrid Name="thread1" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False" Background="White" IsReadOnly="true"
      Width="300" Height="443" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" HeadersVisibility="Column">
    <DataGrid.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridCell" x:Key="borderNone">
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0" />
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0" />
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.Resources>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Поток №1" Width="*" CellStyle="{StaticResource borderNone}">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderStyle>
                <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
                </Style>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderStyle>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding DataThreadsAll}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False" IsReadOnly="true"
                              HeadersVisibility="Column" BorderThickness="0">
                        <DataGrid.Columns>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Width="*" Header="Ri" Binding="{Binding Ri}" />
                            <DataGridTextColumn Width="*" Header="Zi" Binding="{Binding Zi}" />
                            <DataGridTextColumn Width="*" Header="Tk" Binding="{Binding Tk}" />
                        </DataGrid.Columns>
                    </DataGrid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: `HorizontalGridLinesBrush="Transparent" VerticalGridLinesBrush="Transparent"`, ну или `GridLinesVisibility="None"` у первого грида

Comment: @EvgeniyZ подошло, большое спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У DataGrid есть так называемые "линии сетки" (это те, что разделяют каждую ячейку по вертикали и горизонтали). Так, как у вас вложенный DataGrid (без отступов и прочего), их линии и слились в одну сплошную.

Решение тут банально простое, задайте этим линиям цвет (прозрачный например) с помощью [HorizontalGridLinesBrush](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.datagrid.horizontalgridlinesbrush?view=netframework-4.7.2)  / [VerticalGridLinesBrush](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.datagrid.verticalgridlinesbrush?view=netframework-4.7.2), либо вовсе уберите их с помощью [GridLinesVisibility](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.datagrid.gridlinesvisibility?view=netframework-4.7.2).